# Geodesics in the Hyperboloid Model

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Let $\mathbb{H}^2$ be the upper sheet of the hyperboloid defined by $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$ in three-dimensional Minkowski space $(\mathbb{R}^3, g_M)$, where $g_M = \text{diag}(1,1,-1)$. In other words, consider the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane.

I am having trouble showing that the unit speed geodesic at point $p \in \mathbb{H}^2$ in direction $v \in T_p\mathbb{H}^2$ such that $g(v,v) = 1$ is given by $\gamma(t) = \cosh(t)p + \sinh(t)v$.

I tried the following:

Parametrize $\mathbb{H}^2$ by
\begin{equation}
(r, \theta) \subseteq (0, \infty) \times (0, 2\pi) \mapsto (\sinh(r)\cos(\theta), \sinh(r)\sin(\theta), \cosh(r))
\end{equation}

Pulling back the Minkowski metric to our local coordinates I obtain

$$ g = dr^2 + \sinh^2(r)d\theta^2$$

Plugin this into the geodesic equation
\begin{align}
r'' - \theta'^2\sinh(r)\cosh(r) &= 0 \\
\theta''\sinh^2(r) + 2r'\theta'\sinh(r)\cosh(r) &= 0
\end{align}

Because the metric in independent of $\theta$ we find that $\theta'\sinh^2(r)$ is conserved. Plugging this into the first geodesic equation we get

$$r'' - k\frac{\cosh(r)}{\sinh^3(r)} = 0.$$

At this point I am stuck, as there doesn't seem to be a simple solution using these coordinates.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The easiest way is to show that the velocity vector of the curve in Minkowski space is always orthogonal to the hyperboloid.

Comment: Try working out the geodesics on the round sphere directly; it is, like this, a nontrivial computation. (See my differential geometry text, freely linked in my profile, if you get stuck.) Where you are here, the next step is the standard energy trick: Multiply by $r’$ and integrate.

Comment: @Deane Did you mean acceleration vector?

Comment: @TedShifrin, yes. You’re right.